# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, adsense

I am writing a code to display Admob Banner in my Android Application. i have done the following few adjustments in order to achieve this:

- configured google play services library following: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/
- Added

  ```
      <activity
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
  ```

and

```
       <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="4323000" />
```

code in my manifest file, and also added following permissions:

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

- Followed the: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play link to develop a banner in my application.

the problem occurs when i try to run the application it throws the following exception:

```
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:       com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at com.atc.hums.HumsActivity.onCreate(HumsActivity.java:458)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
     05-07 14:51:17.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try to remove the jars then add them again and clean your build, after that run...

Comment: i havent added any jars in the project. i created a sample project apart from my main project and its working fine there but when i try to incorporate in my main project it throws this exception

Comment: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView for this you need to add jar, check your working project properties if there are any jars in libs or in build path

Comment: i had only included included google-play-services_lib which contains com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView, i have not included GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar file i am trying to achieve it through gms

Comment: there is only one jar in libs folder naming android-support-v4.jar and nothing else.

Comment: anyone, any help please?

Comment: Did you like any of the given answers

Comment: basically i figured out that way of adding play service library is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Adding Google Play Services support to your project

As per the [Google Play Services setup guide](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), one does not simply "add the jars".
Since GPS comes bundled with resources, you have to import it as a new seperate project, and reference it from your own, exisiting project.

Please follow the setup guide. I've just verified that I can reference `AdView` successfully from my own project incorporating GPS.

### Ensuring your device supports Google Play Services

GPS is an external service - it's an APK managed by the Play Store app and you need to ensure that the user has the latest GPS APK and/or one that complies with what you wanna do. Here is the guide: [Ensure Devices Have the Google Play services APK](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure).

If the device does not have GPS installed (not a Google device, special ROM, AOSP ROM, old Android, etc...) you can not use AdView.

Comment: i have followed the guide and encorporated the GPS correctly and included it as library project

Comment: does it has something to do with android-support-v4.jar because when i remove this jar it launches the application but it does not load ads and throws the following error Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment

Comment: No. This just means that the app is crashing on earlier missing classes.

Comment: I suppose you did not follow the guide correctly - as I've said - I can reference AdView fine from my own project.

Comment: you mean to say that you are able to refer AdView from your project without adding Google play services as library in ur project?

Comment: AFTER adding GPS as a reference project.

Comment: Did you try referencing any other project libraries? Is "Android dependencies" checked in Project Properties -> Java build path -> Order and export?

Comment: Also - please note my update. Your device/emulator mighty not have GPS installed...

Comment: I have the same problem ,added the play service project and even i check the adview class from xml. I couldn't find out any mistake but getting classnotfound error during run time

Comment: Does your test device have GPS installed? Please mind the last paragraph in my answer. When you're adding the GPS SDK to your project you're linking upon the actual GPS installed on the device.

ALWAYS ensure that the target device has GPS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow these steps

First step : You should login into admob account and add an app there without url.Click on manage app take ,adunitId from there in the xml layout please place following code.

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="youradunitid"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Second step:In main activity ,please do not again add adview ,because you have already add adview in xml do not forget to put loadAdOnCreate = true

Third step:

You already add essential to manifest.

Fourth step :when you run on emulator it gives test ads

Fifth step :Now you are ready to launch on device

Comment: does it has something to do with android-support-v4.jar because when i remove this jar it launches the application but it does not load ads and throws the following error Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment