# Google Advertizer ID in Library

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an SDK where I need the Google Advertiser ID. As per the instructions given in this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html) I attached the code in one of my `.java` files. Now when I tried to include the jar file into a project, it is throwing an error

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/.....

Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info.getId, referenced from method com/../getIdThread
```

Can someone help me with this?

Note: Google Play services library and jar file are added to my SDK.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure that when asking for help with your code, users need to actually see it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

> The advertising ID APIs are supported in Google Play services 4.0+

So you need to first make sure that you have integrated Google Play Services support correctly in your app. Then you need to verify, at runtime, that the user has the latest/necessary Google Play Services installed on his device, prioir to using a Google Play Services feature.

Here is how to do both things, from my asnwer on a similar thread:
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514726/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-ads-adview/23515762#23515762)